# Fantasy book about an underwater civilization

Tags: story-identification, books

The underwater civilization decides to take over land and the main character's mom turns out to be from that colony, the girl eventually ends up falling in love with the prince of the underwater colony.

Comment: Could you give us some more information like when you read this and what the cover of the book looked like?